# gem not installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Ok i keep getting this error

```
Could not find tzinfo-0.3.24 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I am using rvm and i just created a gemset and i have this

```
gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.3)
actionpack (3.0.3)
activemodel (3.0.3)
activerecord (3.0.3)
activeresource (3.0.3)
activesupport (3.0.3)
arel (2.0.7)
bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.7)
devise (1.1.5)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.14)
mime-types (1.16)
mysql (2.8.1)
paperclip (2.3.8)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.3)
railties (3.0.3)
rake (0.8.7)
riddle (1.2.2)
thinking-sphinx (2.0.0)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.24)
warden (1.0.3)
will_paginate (3.0.pre2)
```

and my Gemfile is

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'devise'
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.0', :require => 'thinking_sphinx'
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.3"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.pre2"
```

any ideas...it was working fine till today

Comment: tzinfo 0.3.24 was just released on 15 January 2011.  It seems to be published to rubygems.org and it installs correctly for me, though.

Comment: could this be something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442834/missing-the-rails-2-3-4-gem-even-though-its-installed/4679237#4679237

Comment: Getting the same thing but for activesupport

Comment: How did you end up solving this I have the same issue again after using Devise.

Comment: i solved this by requiring tzinfo while this normally not necessary while requiring activerecord

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try including tzinfo-0.3.24 in your Gemfile and doing bundle exec with the command that gives you the error. Alternatively you could bundle install --development to get the Gems in the vendor folder. Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 3):

After DLL Hell we have Gem Hell. It looks like we have the same [dependency hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) in Ruby as in other communities. Welcome :-)

The gem `tzinfo` with the right version `0.3.24` seems to be missing, or it is not referenced correctly in your Gemfile. Check your Gemfile and your Gemfile.lock. The latter is useful to find out dependencies, and it should be updated if the Gemfile is changed (by running a bundle install).

If you have installed the gems locally, by using `gem install --user-install gemname` or `bundle install --path ~/.gem`, then you maybe have multiple gems in multiple locations. Check out the GEM PATHS by calling a `gem env` command from the command line.

And by the way, you seem to use Rails 3.0.x with the old mysql gem. The mysql2 gem is now the default in Rails 3. I would recommend to use the mysql2 gem instead by adding `gem 'mysql2'` to the GemFile and by using using the mysql2 adapter in your `database.yml`.